# checking that an initial condition holds for the heat equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

I'm trying to follow a [video lecture](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3YXUb2-HjBk&list=PLGCj8f6sgswntUil8yzohR_qazOfYZCg_&index=26&t=15m45s) on solving the heat equation.

> $I) \space u_t = ku_{xx}, x \in \mathbb{R}, t > 0$
>
> $II) \space u(x,0)=\phi (x), $
>
> $k$ is const, $\phi (x) $ is a known function.

An earlier video in lecture series proved these properties:

> 1. If $u(x,t)$ is a solution to $I)$ then for each fixed $y$, the translate
>      $u(x-y,t)$ is also a solution.
> 2. If $u$ is a solution then every derivative of $u$ is also a solution.
> 3. Every linear combination of solutions is also a solution.
> 4. If $S(x,t)$ is a solution then so is its integral. Thus $S(x-y,t)$ is a
>      solution and so is $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} S(x-y,t)g(y)dy$ for each
>      function $g$ that makes the integral converge.
> 5. If $u(x,t)$ is a solution the for each $a>0$ the dilates function
>      $u(\sqrt{a}x,at)$ is also a solution.

Using the the translate and integral properties, you can find this solution to $I)$ as $u(x,t)=\displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} S(x-y,t)\phi(y)dy $

The first part of the video shows that $I)$ holds.

To show that the initial condition $II)$ holds, you begin by doing the following:

$S := \frac{\partial }{\partial x}Q$

$u(x,t)=\displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\partial }{\partial x} Q(x-y,t)\phi(y)dy $

$
\color{green}{\mathbb{\bf*}} \\
=  \displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\partial }{\partial y}[-Q (x-y,t)]\phi(y)dy     $

Using integration by parts:

$- \displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} Q_y (x-y,t)\phi(y)dy     $

$\begin{array}{ll}
w &=\phi(y)     & v_y = Q_y(x-y,t) \\
w_y &=\phi'(y)  & v = -Q(x-y,t)
 \end{array}$

$=-  \left[ -Q (x-y,t)\phi(y)\bigg |_{y \rightarrow -\infty}^{y \rightarrow \infty}- \displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}  -Q (x-y,t)   \phi'(y)dy  \right]$

$=Q (x-y,t)\phi(y)\bigg |_{y \rightarrow -\infty}^{y \rightarrow \infty}- \displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}  Q (x-y,t)   \phi'(y)dy  $

I don't understand what happens on the line labeled $\color{green}{\mathbb{\bf*}}$. Why can you switch from $Q_x$ to $-Q_y$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reasoning seems to be that, letting $z = x-y$, we can use the chain rule to say that $$\frac{\partial Q}{\partial y} = \frac{\partial Q}{\partial z} \frac{\partial z}{\partial y} =  \frac{\partial Q}{\partial z} \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\left(x - y \right)\right) = - \frac{\partial Q}{\partial z} \Longrightarrow \frac{\partial Q}{\partial y} = - \frac{\partial Q}{\partial z}$$ Similarly we can see that $$\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial Q}{\partial z} \frac{\partial z}{\partial x} =  \frac{\partial Q}{\partial z} \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(x - y \right)\right) = \frac{\partial Q}{\partial z} \Longrightarrow \frac{\partial Q}{\partial x} =  \frac{\partial Q}{\partial z} $$

We can combine the results of these two equations to deduce that $$ \frac{\partial Q}{\partial x} = - \frac{\partial Q}{\partial y}$$